# Getting a white page error on a path with an ID - react router dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying use an id while resetting the password. While other pages work fine but the reset page with an id is throwing a white page on Deployment. The reset page is, however, working in localhost.

Setting routing path:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { UserProvider } from "./UserContext";
import ForgotPass from "./components/ForgotPass";
import ResetPassword from "./components/ResetPass";
import RegisterUser from "./components/Register";
import UserLogin from "./components/UserLogin";
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <UserProvider>
        <div className="container px-0">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/register" component={RegisterUser}></Route>
            <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}></Route>
            <Route exact path="/forgot-password" component={ForgotPass}></Route>
            <Route path="/reset/:id" component={ResetPassword}></Route>
            <Route exact path="/" component={UserLogin}></Route>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </UserProvider>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Error log - Chrome:

```
2.2ea4f433.chunk.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
main.93407c2a.chunk.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
```

​Error log - Firefox:

```
The stylesheet https://proj-resetpassword.netlify.app/reset/static/css/2.61b4cb56.chunk.css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”. 7667
The stylesheet https://proj-resetpassword.netlify.app/reset/static/css/main.21b13064.chunk.css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”. 7667
The script from “https://proj-resetpassword.netlify.app/reset/static/js/main.93407c2a.chunk.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.
7667
The script from “https://proj-resetpassword.netlify.app/reset/static/js/2.2ea4f433.chunk.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.
7667
Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
2.2ea4f433.chunk.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
main.93407c2a.chunk.js:1
```

Following is my Reset Page in React

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function ResetPassword() {
  const history = useHistory();
  const [newpass, setNewpass] = useState("");
  const [repeatpass, setRepeatpass] = useState("");
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {};

  return (
    <div className="card card__">
      <p className="title">Update Password</p>
      <div className="reset-img">
        <img
          src="/imgs/key.jpeg"
          className="card-img-top real-img"
          alt="reset-password-img"
        />
      </div>
      <div className="card-body">
        <p className="hidden invalid">
          <small className="text-danger">
            Password do not match. Please try again.
          </small>
        </p>
        <p className="hidden valid">
          <small className="text-success">
            You have successfully registered your new password.
          </small>
        </p>
        <p className="hidden unauthorized">
          <small className="text-danger">
            Unauthorized Access. Verify your email again.
          </small>
        </p>
        <form className="reset-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="inputPass1">New Password</label>
            <input
              type="password"
              className="form-control my-2"
              id="inputPass1"
              aria-describedby="passHelp"
              required
              onChange={(e) => setNewpass(e.target.value)}
            />
            <label htmlFor="inputPass2">Repeat Password</label>
            <input
              type="password"
              className="form-control my-2"
              id="inputPass2"
              aria-describedby="passHelp"
              required
              onChange={(e) => setRepeatpass(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary my-2">
            Reset
          </button>
        </form>
        <div className="links">
          <Link to={"/forgot-password"} className="link">
            Forgot Password
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ResetPassword;
```

**UserLogin, RegisterUser, Dashboard, ForgotPass - these all pages display well except the ResetPassword page.**

Please help me to figure out a solution. Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean by 'a white page error'? is there any error in console? what is the error?

Comment: @daniel93 Sorry about that! I have updated the question with error log. Thank you!

Comment: usually there is a function or class declared and then will return something, like DOM elements you want to show in your page, however, you should put more logic code in the question in order to see where the problem is.

Comment: @EL-MehdiLoukach I have added here reset page as well. Please take a look. Thank you!

Comment: @erik you can use useParams, i'll write an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are not rendering a component, but have only JSX syntax (and some imports) in the file defining your `Router`.

You need to return your `Router` JSX from from either a function (a component defined as a function) or from the render function of a `Component`-extending class.
The JavaScript runtime has no idea what to do with your `<Router>{/*...*/}</Router>` JSX as it is now.
Take a look at what your `ResetPassword` component is doing and follow along as an example of a component defined as a function, or take a look at the [Components and Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) documentation.

Additionally, you probably want to be importing your `RegisterUser`, `Dashboard`, `ForgotPass`, `ResetPassword`, and `UserLogin` components in that file - otherwise the runtime would not be able to find those references.

###### A component as a function

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

function MyRouterComponent() {
  return (
    <Router>
      { /* ... */ }
    </Router>
  );
}
```

##### A component as a `Component`-extending class

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

class MyRouterComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        { /* ... */ }
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe that this particular problem has to do anything with the rendering method, otherwise react will NOT RUN the application on the browser ! However, and as it seems that the code provided is not really complete, but the actual problem was how to get the ID from the URL params using react-router-dom.

Comment: @EL-MehdiLoukach The OP stated that his React application is displaying only a white page, so it is not running. Additionally, OP provided this error log: `2.2ea4f433.chunk.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`. That, along with the provided code, points towards this being the cause. OP's code does not make an attempt at getting an `id` from the URL. OP should provide an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if this is not the issue.

Comment: you're 100% right, but in this case the code will generate a blank page, even if there is no error on the client layer, react component will not be shown on the client side, because it's simply require and ID and can't find it.

Comment: @j1mbl3s , I apologize for not being clear earlier. The other components display as desired except the reset page with an id parameter (on server). It is the only component that throws a white page. This, however, works in localhost.

Answer (score 0):

In order to display a page that requires and `id` recovered from the URL as you're trying to do, there is an option called `useParams` comes with `react-router-dom`, and you can use it like this :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useParams, Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export default function ResetPassword(){
     const history = useHistory();
     const [newpass, setNewpass] = useState("");
     const [repeatpass, setRepeatpass] = useState("");
     const handleSubmit = async (e) => {/*HANDLING SUBMIT ALGORITHM*/};
     let {id} = useParams(); // This variable can be used as any other react element inside this function.
     return (
        /* HERE YOU CAN PUT YOUR HTML ELEMENTS OR REACT COMPONENTS*/
        <h1> {id} </h1>
       /* END ID DISPLAY */
       <div className="card card__">
  <p className="title">Update Password</p>
  <div className="reset-img">
    <img
      src="/imgs/key.jpeg"
      className="card-img-top real-img"
      alt="reset-password-img"
    />
  </div>
  <div className="card-body">
    <p className="hidden invalid">
      <small className="text-danger">
        Password do not match. Please try again.
      </small>
    </p>
    <p className="hidden valid">
      <small className="text-success">
        You have successfully registered your new password.
      </small>
    </p>
    <p className="hidden unauthorized">
      <small className="text-danger">
        Unauthorized Access. Verify your email again.
      </small>
    </p>
    <form className="reset-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="inputPass1">New Password</label>
        <input
          type="password"
          className="form-control my-2"
          id="inputPass1"
          aria-describedby="passHelp"
          required
          onChange={(e) => setNewpass(e.target.value)}
        />
        <label htmlFor="inputPass2">Repeat Password</label>
        <input
          type="password"
          className="form-control my-2"
          id="inputPass2"
          aria-describedby="passHelp"
          required
          onChange={(e) => setRepeatpass(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary my-2">
        Reset
      </button>
    </form>
    <div className="links">
      <Link to={"/forgot-password"} className="link">
        Forgot Password
      </Link>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
      )
}
```

However, I highly recommend for you to check [react-router-dom docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params).

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. I really appreciate it. I made changes like you said still getting the same white page. Correct me if I am wrong, I am getting a sense that the main culprit is "/" (forward slash). Path works as desired if there is no forward slash at the end and the moment I put forward slash to add an ID, it throws an error. I am not sure why is this happening on deployment.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is - In browser, url displays components as desired if there is no forward slash at the end and the moment I put forward slash to add an ID, it throws an error.

Comment: @erik try to add `exact` to`path="/reset/:id"` in router declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Simple trick seem to be working for me.

Go to your base html page.

In my case public/index.html and Within the `<head>` tag add `<base href="/">`.